# Supported datatypes for indexes when using GQLAlchemy and Memgrpah

Tags: memgraphdb

I see [Memgraph can index almost any datatype](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/under-the-hood/indexing), which of these datatypes are supported if GQLAlchemy is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just taken a quick look at GQLAlchmey codebase, documentation and issues. As far as I can tell via GQLAlchmey you should be able to create an index of any label+property pair using of any of the types.